# Writing memory violation error when using this

Tags: c++, this

```
void main()
{
    shape *a[200];
    int user_choice = 0, pilihan = 0, count = 0;
    while (user_choice != 3)
    {
        cout << "---===Menu===---" << endl;
        cout << "(1). Add Shape" << endl;
        cout << "(2). Show All" << endl;
        cout << "(3). Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Masukkan Pilihan Anda : ";
        cin >> user_choice;
        if (user_choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "---===Menu===---" << endl;
            cout << "(1). Lingkaran" << endl;
            cout << "(2). Segitiga" << endl;
            cout << "(3). Back" << endl;
            cout << "Masukkan Pilihan Anda : ";
            cin >> pilihan;
            if (pilihan == 1)
            {
                count++;
                int radius;
                cout << "Masukkan Radius : ";
                cin >> radius;
                a[count] = new lingkaran(radius);
            }
            else if (pilihan == 2)
            {
                count++;
                int alas, tinggi;
                cout << "Masukkan Alas : ";
                cin >> alas;
                cout << "Masukkan Tinggi : ";
                cin >> tinggi;
                a[count] = new segitiga(alas, tinggi);
                /*  for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
                {
                    a[x]->set2(alas, tinggi);
                }
                count++;*/
            }
            else if (pilihan == 3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (user_choice == 2)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
            {
                cout << "test1" << endl;
                a[x]->show();
                cout << "test2" << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so basically, i think i do it right but my void show(), they just opened and then close by itself.. any help suggestion?, *segitiga = triangle, *lingkaran = circle

```
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
{
    cout << "test1" << endl;
    a[x]->show();
    cout << "test2" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This may help you: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please format your code properly .... pretty please?   (Then please post less so that it's a minimal example)

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the first object at index 1, not 0.
Thus, the first array element has an indeterminate value, and it's just luck that you're crashing.

If `count` is your number of elements, that's also the index you want to create the next object in.

Increment `count` *after* adding the new element:

```
if (pilihan == 1)
{
    int radius;
    cout << "Masukkan Radius : ";
    cin >> radius;
    a[count] = new lingkaran(radius);
    count++;
}
```

or write to the `count-1`:th element:

```
if (pilihan == 1)
{
    count++;
    int radius;
    cout << "Masukkan Radius : ";
    cin >> radius;
    a[count-1] = new lingkaran(radius);
}
```

but this variant is slightly harder to understand, in my opinion.